# How to Repair my Dropped Refrigerator

Tags: repair, doors, refrigerator

I ordered a new hinge and brake for the fridge/freezer a friend dropped.  The problem is the door hangs too low on the left side.

[image: damaged hinge]

My thinking was that the bottom of the door got pushed out to the right because of the way the hinge warped, but looking closer it would appear the door itself is a bit dented.  Should it be ok to try to hammer/bend that out, or should I be ordering more parts before taking things apart to fix?

Comment: It's hard to tell from this picture how the door was damaged. Clearly, this foot is bent, but it doesn't look like the top has moved very much at all (judging by the 4 screws in the back of the white bracket). Do you have a better picture with a wider shot?  Btw, very fitting site to use for hosting this picture.

Comment: Where the hinge enters the door itself seems to be bent about 15 degrees, it's hard to capture that in a photo.  On the other hand, the bottom left corner of the door sticks out on the right side about 1/4" farther than the top of it.  It looks like I only have to raise the opposite side of the door about 1/8" in order to get a good seal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say if this will ever close right from the picture, and given how old the question is, I'm guessing you've repaired or replaced it by now. But for those that encounter this issue in the future, doors themselves can warp and be easily unwarped.

You need to loosen the screws hidden under the gasket of the door, and with them loose straighten the door. This is typically done when the top or bottom of the door closes before the other so the gasket doesn't seal, so I'm not sure how well that will work if a corner is high rather than not closing. When re-tightening the screws, start with the 8 screws closest to the 4 corners, and then double check your alignment (you can make small adjustments still) before tightening the remaining screws.